# How to adjust to webpage into horizontal scroll view like google currents do?

Tags: java, android, jquery, ios, html

In the Google currents app, a user can swipe left and right to browse the content. I know that view is a webview.

But I dont know how to make the web fit the mobile height, scroll horizontally and smoothly.

Is it using HTML5, jQuery, or just a native code to handle it?

Comment: is something like this?
http://www.ladehoffcondominios.com.br/#home (try to change the page in the top menu)

Comment: Thx you answer, but No ~ no .
in Google Currents ,you can see the Article in horizontal scroll, then next article. No Verticle move, just swipe right , right.